# 'Take after' usage with abstract concepts

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I use phrasal verb *take after* with things and abstract concepts when I want to emphasise similarity and inheritance? For example, is it correct to say either of these:

> 1. Idea A takes after idea B more than any other.
> 2. Idea A takes after idea B.

Comment: “More after” sounds wrong.

Comment: I would have said that the expression *take after* is usually used in connection with a person, not a idea.

Comment: (1) would be "takes after idea B more than any other"

Comment: @TrevorD Agreed -  at http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/take-after-sb the DO is restricted to a person: _take after_ **sb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Take after* in common usage means that a person resembles an older relative, especially a parent or grandparent. But there is nothing to prevent you from using it as a metaphor, as long as the meaning is clear to your reader. If you feel the relationship between *A* and *B* is like the relationship normally conveyed by *take after* (*A* is similar to *B*, an older relative), then by all means write that. For example, you might write that Perl or Java take after C.

*Take after* has historically been used of people fairly broadly to mean imitation and resemblance:

> **take**, *v.*
>   **XI.** Intransitive uses in idiomatic combination with prepositions.
>   **73. Take after —.**
>   **a.** To follow the example of; to imitate; hence, to resemble (a parent, ancestor, predecessor, superior, etc.) in nature, character, habits, appearance, or other quality.
>   <sup>**1553** T. W<sub><sup>ILSON</sup></sub> *Rhet.* (1580) 112 If the Nurse be of a noughtie nature, the childe must take thereafter.
>
>   **1657** H<sub><sup>EYLIN</sup></sub> *Ecclesia Vind.* Gen. Pref., His Followers all take after him in this particular.
>
>   **1678** P<sub><sup>HILLIPS</sup></sub> (ed. 4) s.v. *Imitatives, Patrissare*, to take after the Father, or imitate his actions, humor, or fashion.
>
>   **1892** *Gd. Words* Nov. 784/2, I take after my mother’s family.</sup>
>   **† b.** ? To conceive a desire for or inclination to.
>   <sup>**1707** *Curios. in Husb. & Gard.* 6 Men take strangely after this their first Imployment.</sup>

### References

The Google search [ *define take after* ] returns a definition and links to various dictionary entries for the phrase.

*A New English Dictionary on Historical Principles*, Vol. IX, Part II, Su–Th, Sect. T, p. 36ff.

Comment: Link to that reference? Actually, how do you get a link to -all- volumes?

Comment: Links to most NED volumes are listed on our general reference page here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2574/14073